# Check if input is from console

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-artisan

I want to share a variable of my views with:

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        \Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
        $customers = Customer::get();
        \View::share('customers', $customers);
    }
}
```

it works as expected, but when I want to migrate my tables via artisan it throws an error, that the table for `customers` was not found because it is checked BEFORE the migration starts. So I need something like

```
if(!artisan_request) {
    //request to laravel is via web and not artisan
}
```

But I haven't found anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can check if you are running in the console by using

```
app()->runningInConsole()
```

Underneath that, all it does is check the interface type

```
return php_sapi_name() == 'cli' || php_sapi_name() == 'phpdbg'
```

You can find more on the [PHP Docs site](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-sapi-name.php)

Comment: No need to use `app()` instance, second one is preferable.

Comment: @Buraco not at all. First one is preferred. I was simply showing what goes on underneath the method.

Answer (score 14):

To detect whether the app is running in console, you can do something like this:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;

if(App::runningInConsole())
{
  // app is running in console
}
```

See, [illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:520](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php)

Comment: it's not static

Comment: @drakonli The App facade allows for that.